How can I attach to an existing VS Code instance with an extension already running for debugging?
I have a Visual Studio Code instance already running with an extension I am developing. I would like to attach to this existing instance for debugging purposes without launching a new VS Code instance. How can I achieve this?
I started the first instance with the following command to inspect and break at port 9229 and installed my .vsix file:
code --inspect-brk=9229
Next, I started a second instance with the following launch configuration, but I am not able to attach the debugger successfully:
"name": "Attach to Extension Host",
"type": "node",
"request": "attach",
"port": 9229,
"address": "localhost",
"restart": false,
